# Radius of Convergence...very tricky question using very little information

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, power-series

Even one of the maths gurus at my university struggled to get a proof out for this... so I'm almost completely lost!

This is the question: Let $a_{n}$ be a sequence of positive real numbers for which $s:=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_{n}^{\frac{1}{n}}$ exists. If $0<s<\infty$, show that the radius of convergence for:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{n}$$

is $\dfrac{1}{s}$. What happens in the case $s=0$ and $s=\infty$

Ok... so I could perform the ratio test, where:

$$r=\left|\dfrac{a_{n+1}x^{n+1}}{a_{n}x^{n}}\right|=\left|\dfrac{a_{n+1}x}{a_{n}}\right|$$

...which should somehow help us get to our solution of 1/s. Now, we have a power series, but this stuff is new enough that I'm completely at a loss as to how to use the limit to prove this result. Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Who is your maths guru and what is your university?

Comment: Just a friend and just a place. Not entirely comfortable sharing information such as that sorry.

Comment: Then why mention these circumstances in the question? Anyway I am not impressed by the *guruness* of your so-called maths gurus.

Answer (score 1):

The [radius of convergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence) is defined to be maximum value of $r$, such that $|x|<r\implies \sum{a_nx^n}$ converges  then the series converges.

Use [root test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test) to arrive at the result.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how that allows me to get to the result of R=1/s.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, even if the root formula gives a limit, the ratio sequence does not have to converge. Just take
$$
a_n=\begin{cases}2s^n&\text{ for odd }n\\s^n&\text{ for even }n\end{cases}
$$

---

Then consider $\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_nx^n|}<1$.